# How to find dead code in C language Project with gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, dead-code

I need to find the dead code(functions not used) in my "C" language Project(having multiple C files) with gcc compiler. Please let me know the gcc options to find the dead code. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean something like the -Wunused-* flags?

Answer (score 4):

For unused static functions, see [Ed King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472459/ed-king)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52545524/8316315).

For global functions you could try this: Build the project twice, once as usual and once with `-ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections` (the first is a compiler flag, the second a linker flag).  Then you can run `nm` on the generated binaries to obtain a list of symbols for both runs.  The linker will have removed unused functions in the second run, so that is your list of dead functions.

This assumes a common target like ELF, the binutils linker, and that the final binaries are not stripped of their symbol table.

Comment: Inlined functions will also not be shown, so don't forget to deactivate optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GCC compiler option `-Wunused-function` to warn you of unused `static` functions. I'm not sure how you would detect unused 'public' functions though, save for looking at the map file for functions that haven't been linked.